# pyxmpp - How to send raw XML

Tags: python, xml, xmpp

How can I send raw XML code using pyxmpp?

something like:

```
 c.send("<presence to='jid@domain.com/resource'/>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall it right (can't find an API reference to it now thou), it's

```
c.stream.write_raw("<presence to='jid@domain.com/resource/'>")
```